# Modal view before UITabBarController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ios7, ios8

Im trying to present a modal view controller from subclass of UITabBarController. I present it from viewDidLayoutSubviews method. Everything works fine on iOS 7 but in iOS 8 when app stars i still breafly see TabBarControllers first tab. 
TabBarController is set as initial view controller in storyboard.

Is this even a good way to present it or there is something for iOS 8 that i dont know?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the rep to post a comment, so I'll seek clarification and provide guidance through this answer.

Is the intention that the modally presented view controller will be the first thing people see when they launch the app? And then I suppose it gets dismissed, and behind it will be the tabbar controller? How is your storyboard currently set up for the modal view controller if the tabbar is set to be the initial view controller?

One place to start could be to move to code to `viewWillLoad` or `viewDidLoad` rather than `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. I could also suggest to just make the modal VC the initial view controller